# Play MP3 from .net code

Tags: .net, audio, mp3

I am getting married this coming Saturday (May 30 2009). We are poor. So, instead of hiring a DJ, I want my friend to kick off mp3 playlists from a laptop to be played through a PA system.

Well I had a vision for some software that would be perfect for this. Here is that vision:
[image]

I want this to be so that my friend can't screw this up and I think that if my vision were a reality then there would be no screwing up.

And now for the programming question? How can I play mp3's from .net code? I am currently experimenting with NAudio, but I don't know if I can make it fade the files in/out.

Are there any other free libraries out there that could help me? Thanks for any input. Time is of the essence.

## PEOPLE!

Focus on the programming question! If I ever need to work with audio in the future, your answers could be the keys to my destiny.

Comment: You can do all this from windows media player already

Comment: And, it will take longer than 4 days to build this and have it be stable/reliable.  If you want to live to see the wedding night, go with something proven.

Comment: I seriously don't think that it would take me that long if I had a good mp3 library. 2 days max.

Comment: Warning sign #1: "2 days max" total time listed without a precise item-by-item breakdown of where that 2 days is going. Warning sign #2: Reinventing the wheel during a time-critical application. Warning sign #3: spending "2 days" of the week leading up to the wedding messing around with a coding application that won't be used afterwards.

Comment: I see you have added "focus on the programming question" but the majority of your question is defining the specs for your project. Perhaps you should cut out everything that's irrelevant, such as talking about your time constraints and the fact that you're getting married. Focus your question on what you want and remove the excess. GIGO

Comment: Oh yeah - warning sign #4: Time-critical application that relies upon learning a new API. If you ever "need to work with audio in the future", I'm presuming you'll have more than a week to work out the kinks you'll inevitably run into.

Comment: Who said I didn't have a schedule? Well... I don't but I still never said that. I try to make my questions on SO fun and interesting and this is the thanks I get?! What I should be hearing are thing like, "Simply amazing! This brave young man is overwhelmed with the stress of planning a wedding and appeasing his bride, yet he still manages to absorb new programming knowledge day in and day out. He deserves 10 medals and a parade. The next high paying developer position I hear of, I will recommend him so highly, he will no doubt land the position. Bravo! Bravo!"

Comment: lol +1 to your last comment for absurdity. I'll assume you were making a joke.

Comment: It's true. Cut out the cruft and the nitpicky devs won't have anything irrelevant to pick at.

Comment: If you removed only the part "I'm getting married this saturday" and just said that you need an app to play through a PA, you wouldn't take nearly as much abuse. It's not the project spec people rankle at, it's the fact that you're going to be coding/QA testings for the days up to your wedding.

Comment: QA Testing?!                 !

Comment: Heh. +1 to that comment, it made me laugh out loud xD

Comment: @devinb reinventing the wheel for one-time use is wasteful regardless of how imaginary that schedule is. The only defense for doing this is curiosity/enjoyment.

Comment: There are a lot of great suggestions on libraries to help with playing audio, and that's what I was really going for. I'm not really going to try to write the program. Thanks for the great responses.

Comment: Ronnie, edit your post to say that and you might get some upvotes. ;)

Comment: If I edit my post, then all of the comments will lose context.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're describing sounds like functionality programs like iTunes and Windows Media Player have had for years, and I would recommend just using one of those two programs. However, if you do want to play MP3s from .NET, a Google search found me this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/mp3player.aspx and this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/ManWMF.aspx

Also, if your wedding is in 4 days, this probably not the best idea. I wouldn't waste your time writing a media player. If you want it to be polished and idiot-proof, use iTunes. If you want to write a media player, do it after your wedding.

Comment: This is a very old question, but I'll just mention that your first link is to a C++ project.

Answer (score 7):

By far the simplest and easiest solution here is to use the **Windows Media Player COM control**. [This page](http://grouplab.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/cookbook/index.php/VisualStudio/HowToUseWindowsMediaPlayerToPlayAudioAndVideo) offers a good guide to getting started with this approach. Just adjusting the volume level with a timer could create a fade in/out effect.

If you want full control over playback, then there's always the [**DirectShow.NET**](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) option, although this is probably overkill for you're task. What is more, it's quite painful to use unless you already have some amount of experience with the unmanaged DirectShow API. However, as I said, I would try to stay away from this if possible.

**Edit:** I have also now realised that the [`Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.aspx) namespace could offer a nice managed solution for your task. It should certainly give more control than the WMP control (and is purely .NET rather than COM, as bonus). The only slight disadvantage is that it requires the XNA Framework 3.0 to be referenced.

Answer (score 3):

Download [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/). You have better things to do a week before your wedding than write another MP3 player. MediaMonkey even has a DJ mode that locks your system so that your guests can't change your playlists.

Answer (score 1):

As I said before,

> "There are a lot of great suggestions on libraries to help with playing audio, and that's what I was really going for. I'm not really going to try to write the program. Thanks for the great responses."

Just for those who are curious: For my wedding, I used Winamp 5.whatever and saved playlists for different parts of the wedding and prefixing the filenames with 01, 02, ... so they would show up in order in the filesystem.

To normalize the audio I downloaded a plugin called [RockSteady](http://www.winamp.com/plugins/details/1099), which worked great. For fading on stop/pause/between songs, in Options -> Preferences -> Plugins -> Output -> Nullsoft DirectSound Output Configuration -> Fading Tab I set "on end of song" to 6000 ms and "on pause/stop" to 15000 ms. Then on the other tab I checked the "Logarithmic Fades" checkbox.

These settings made the audio sound nice and professional.

Answer (score 0):

You're reinventing the wheel. If "time is of the essence" just create the playlist files for your friend and put them all in the same directory. Label them 00 - Prelude, 01 - Processional, etc.

See [this article on the M3U format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) for more info. You can list the files to play in this text based format. Or just use a media player such as winamp or windows media player to create the playlist files.

Comment: Software developers know that we have to give people what they need, not what they think they need. To prevent us from helping you properly, shorten your question.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with most of the others here.  I think you should really try to uncomplicate things by using another already build free option like itunes, Winamp or WMP.  If you really want to learn something new, do this just for fun after when you won't be under so much pressure to make it work.

If, however you REALLY want to go through with this I think http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/ should do what you want.

Comment: I don't really know, but doesn't Ffmpeg seem like a bit of overkill to play a simple MP3 file?

Answer (score 0):

Really interesting, but in my opinion you should use an already existent solution.

However, you can check these links:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/cswavplay.aspx?df=100&forumid=13779&exp=0&fr=26&select=736865
- http://www.csharphelp.com/archives/archive264.html

Also the Windows media player com control should be a good option.

PS: I don't know if I can include a question in an answer, but How have you made that graphic?

Comment: What are you talking about? I drew it on paper. JK. Balsamiq Mockups is the software I used.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others, make several playlists and just load/play them with windows media player.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped mp3 decoder library and made it available for .net developers.  You can find it here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpg123net/

Included are the samples to convert mp3 file to PCM, and read ID3 tags.

You need something like waveOut wrapper, that I know it exists, and there you go!