# how to play chunks of mp3 bytes from sql server, transferred to desktop client (by wcf) using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, mp3, desktop, playback

I have `"chunks"` of audio(in `mp3` format) on a `sql` database i.e, you can imagine a `mp3` file ,divided to equal size of chunks and each chunk is saved on a record on a `sql` server db. these `chunks` are returned to the desktop client(s) via a `WCF` service. of course the client asks for the next chunk when it receives one.(they will be received in order ,so the header comes first!)
 here is the question ,how may I play this received `chunks` in my desktop app one by one in sequent?
can i play them back to back using each chunk to buffer the player?

**please notice :**
-the desktop client is in C#
-the player can be wmp if it works for this purpose!
-chunks are saved in bytes 
-for some reasons the "chunk on sql " system is already implemented by someone else..i just need to find a way to play them like a stream on desktop

thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason to believe you can't concatenate these *chunks* into one contiguous `byte[]`?

Comment: yes, actually I don't know if they are finished or any farther coming at the time of playing !

Comment: Okay, we can manage both ways, it's just more complex if all you have is chunks.

Comment: im afraid they are all chunks and what I meant was that they might be being added to the sql while being requested by the client..therefore there is no way to know the exact end of them at the time of playing !

Comment: I'm left to assume that the order they are played in is irrelevant then?

Comment: not irrelevant ..they are just in order ,being recorded ,uploaded  and added in order..so when u receive them and play them .one by one and back to back , u will not realize they are separate ...smooth like a stream I may say!

Comment: Play the first chunk as soon as it is downloaded. If the connection is fast enough to handle streaming, the second chunk will be done downloading by the time the first chunk is done playing. When the first chunk is finished playing (every media player control has an event to signify playback is complete) just immediately feed it the next chunk and it should play seamlessly.

Comment: the chunks are like 10 seconds,so transfer would be fast enough I think,and about immediate feeding,how can I do that? just by saving the chunks to a file and update it every time after receiving a new one?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353562/play-mp3-from-stream

Comment: ohhh...thanks..actually we narrowed down to put them in a stream,anyways I will try that and reflect the result!

Comment: I used the irrklang component and experienced lots of difficulties in playing the chunks,i guess im going to ask the chunk providers to send the entire mp3 files with the same length(10 sec) through wcf so it will be playable certainly on this side..though might not be very smooth..!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your mp3 player can play from a System.IO.Stream object, implement your own stream class with the following

```
    private byte[] GetDataBlock()
    {
        while (data.Count == 0)
        {
            //TODO: Read More Data from the database
            index = 0;
        }
        return data.Peek();
    }
    private void RemoveDataBlock()
    {
        data.Dequeue();
        index = 0;
    }

    Queue<byte[]> data = new Queue<byte[]>();
    int index = 0;
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {            
        int left = count;
        int dstIndex = 0;

        while (left > 0)
        {
            byte[] front = GetDataBlock();

            int available = front.Length - index;
            // how much from the current block can we copy?
            int length = (available <= left) ? available : left;
            Array.Copy(front, index, buffer, dstIndex, length);
            dstIndex += length;
            left -= length;
            index += length;
            // read all the bytes in the array?
            if (length == available)
            {
                RemoveDataBlock();
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
```

What this does is place the chunks of data into a queue.  The Read method reads them out in order they were added.

This code will only read 1 chunk at a time, but could be expanded to read on a separate thread and buffer up a number of chunks.

Comment: thanks I am going to try it...the basic assumption you made i.e, being able to play from a stream object is another part of problem actually, by any chance do you know any free mp3 player capable of doing it?

Comment: This might answer it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912356/play-mp3-from-net-code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a method of ordering them appropriately in the database when the user requests them, your breakdown is fairly simple. In pseudo code

1. user requests mp3
2. do:
3. check for and send to client the available chunks
4. if there are chunks to play, play them (add them to the stream) in the defined order
5. while: the footer hasn't been encountered in those chunks //end do

essentially, send the chunks as available to the user until the footer is encountered, playing the chunks as if they were complete.

Comment: true,but I don't know how to feed that stream of chunks  to media player while im downloading them , I don't know any method to do that!